# How do I get a horse/horse saddle?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I craft a Horse Saddle, or find a horse in Minecraft 1.5.2?

Answer (score 5):

There are no horses in 1.5.2, only in 1.6+

[Saddles](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Saddle) are uncraftable and can only be found in dungeons, abandoned mineshafts, Nether Fortresses, Desert and Jungle Temples. They can also be found in blacksmith's chests in [villages](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villages), by [fishing](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fishing), or by [trading](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading) with villagers.

Comment: Is the trade available in 1.7?  I thought it was introduced in the 1.8 snapshots.

Comment: @MBraedley Trading with villagers was added ages ago. Saddles from trades were added in 1.3.1.

Comment: @MBraedley "Horse Saddle" is just a regular saddle (works on pigs, donkeys, horses).  "Horse Armor" is more difficult to obtain.

Comment: @John I know that.  I just didn't think that villagers traded saddles until recently.

Comment: @John In earlier snapshots, the was such thing called a Horse Saddle(with crafting recipe).

Comment: @MBraedley I didn't!